# Object.entries does not cause rendering, although data is populated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

What I am trying to do is render the contents of the dictionary corresponding to each index, which I will have to modify later (both the key and value). Therefore, I have the following dictionary.

```
{0: {a: 'b'}
1: {c: 'd'}
2: {e: 'f'}
```

What I would want is to render it within a React.Fragment. Although indexed_data (the above dictionary) is populated, for some reason nothing is rendered in my component. I tried changing the way I returned the keys and objects with Object.keys or Object.values, but nothing worked. Can anyone please help me figure out what is going on? Thank you so much!

```
let i = 0;
let indexed_data = {};
const { state } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(state)) {
      let object = {};
      object[key] = value;
      indexed_data[i] = object;
      i += 1;
    }
  }, []);

 return Object.entries(indexed_data).map((elem, index) => {
    return Object.entries(elem).map((number, product) => {
      <div>
        <React.Fragment>
          {
            <div className="column">
              <EditText name="item" defaultValue={product} />
            </div>
          }
        </React.Fragment>
      </div>;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Why not have a simpler object like `{ a: 'b', c: 'd'...}`? Those indexes don't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Andy Hi! The reason is that i need to be able to modify both the key and index, but to also delete the pair. Without an index, if i modified both the key and value, i would lose track.

Comment: Hi! Then have an array of objects: `[{a: 'b'}...]`, and use the `map` index when you loop over the array as an data attribute on the element you're updating/changing. And `indexed_data` should probably be a state that you can update. It sort of depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you! That is a good idea, but i would have to separately keep track of what i deleted so far. What I am trying to do is render these pairs and be able to modify the key or the value, and also delete them. I found some implementations that were working, but everytime i deleted something or changed the key, the order in the dictionary changed but the page was not rerendered. So that led to issues with the delete buttons.

Comment: So is the basic idea that you have a list of items showing on the page that have delete buttons attached to them, and you want to make sure that when you delete an item the data is updated? Something like that?

Comment: Yep, sorry, I just edited my comment a bit late :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243005/discussion-between-marry-poppins-and-andy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So let's switch things around a little bit.

Have an array of objects (I've switched the keys/values for something more informative for this example):

```
const arr = [{name: 'Bob'}, {name: 'Sue'}, {name: 'Rita'}];
```

Have two states: the first is the original data (in case you need to revert to it at some point); the second is the filtered data.

You can then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the filtered array to produce your JSX.

I can't replicate everything in your code but this example should help clear up some misunderstanding.

```js
const { useState } = React;

// Pass in the data
function Example({ arr }) {

  // Initialise your states
  const [ data, setData ] = useState(arr);
  const [ filtered, setFiltered ] = useState(arr);

  // `getItems` gets the filtered array as an argument
  function getItems(filtered) {

    // `map` returns a new array
    return filtered.map((item, i) => {

      // For each object we grab the key/value from the first
      // element of its `Object.entries` (an array)
      const [key, value] = Object.entries(item)[0];

      // And return some JSX
      // Note that we're using the `map` index to add
      // both a key, and a data attribute to both the list
      // item, and the button. We'll use that id when we
      // remove the item.
      return (
        <li key={i} data-id={i}>
        {key}: {value}
        <button data-id={i} onClick={deleteItem}>Delete</button>
        </li>
      );

    });

  }

  // When we click on a button we use the id (coerced from a data
  // attribute string to a number) then filter out
  // all the objects where the id doesn't match the filter index
  // And then we reset the filtered state with that new array
  function deleteItem(e) {
    const { dataset: { id } } = e.target;
    const a = filtered.filter((item, i) => Number(id) !== i);
    setFiltered(a);
  }

  // Resets the data
  function reset() {
    setFiltered(data);
  }

  // Now we just call `getItems` with the
  // filtered state as an argument
  return (
    <div> 
      <ul>{getItems(filtered)}</ul>
      <button onClick={reset}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );

}

const arr = [{name: 'Bob'}, {name: 'Sue'}, {name: 'Rita'}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example arr={arr} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
button { margin-left: 1em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```